# why GDB crushed in VScode when I click rigester button?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What's this "register" button used for when debugging in VScode? When I click it, GDB crushed and I don't know why.If I want to check registers when debugging, what am I supposed to do?
[when I click this button, GDB crushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF6Lw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem just like you.

The reason for it is that there's a bug in GCC 8.1. When you use the `info registers` command in GDB, the GDB crashes. You can try to use other GCC versions to solve this problem.

You can see the bug [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26304).